# Windows Photo Viewer - Yellow?

Tags: color-profiles, windows-photo-viewer

I have a Dell M4500 attached to a dock with two Samsung SyncMaster 2443. For some reason all images in Windows Photo viewer have a yellow background and it distorts the image. Viewing the same image in say Paint or QuickTime PictureViewer doesn't have this problem.

Any ideas what's going on?

P.S. A colleague has the exact same set-up but instead has two Dell Monitors and this doesn't happen for him.

--EDIT
I should point out it's Win 7 Pro x64

Cheers
Tony

Comment: Are you on Windows 7 or maybe Vista? I think it might have something to do with that. I've noticed that they added a yellow-ish background to the photo viewer in 7 at least. (I skipped Vista, but it's probably the same there.) Although I don't know about your friend's comp.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

AH HA!

It was all to do with colour profiles on the Samsung monitors.

This Microsoft article holds the solution: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/939395

(If you're using more than one monitor you'll need to set the profiles individually)

In case the link ever dies here are the instructions:

> 1. Click Start, type Color Management in the Start Search box, and then
>      press ENTER.
> 2. In the Color Management dialog box, click to select the Use my
>      settings for this device check box.
> 3. In the Profiles associated with this device list, click the color
>      profile that you want to remove, and
>      then click Remove.
> 4. Note If you receive a warning message, click Yes.
> 5. Click Close to close the Color Management dialog box.
> 6. Restart the computer.

The profile I used was sRGB IEC61966-2.1

In Windows 8, you don't need to restart.

Comment: Five years later, exact same problem here, different monitor.  Followed your steps to the letter, no more sepia toned pics. This must be the reason for Beethoven starting his second symphony the way he did.  Thank you, for real.  Plus One on both your question and your answer.

Comment: Glad this was helpful for you :)